# How can I iterate over a map of <String, POJO>?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, pojo

I've got a `Map<String, Person>` (actually I'm using a more complex POJO but simplifying it for the sake of my question)

`Person` looks like :

```
class Person
{
  String name;
  Integer age;

  //accessors
}
```

How can I iterate through this map, printing out the key, then the person name, then the person age such as :

```
System.out.println(String.format("Key : %s Name : %s Age : %s", a, b, c));
```

- A being the key from Map<**String**, Person>
- B being the name from Person.getName()
- C being the age from Person.getAge()

I can pull all of the values from the map using .values() as detailed in the [HashMap docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), but I'm a bit unsure of how I can get the keys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[What about entrySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet())

```
HashMap<String, Person> hm = new HashMap<String, Person>();

hm.put("A", new Person("p1"));
hm.put("B", new Person("p2"));
hm.put("C", new Person("p3"));
hm.put("D", new Person("p4"));
hm.put("E", new Person("p5"));

Set<Map.Entry<String, Person>> set = hm.entrySet();

for (Map.Entry<String, Person> me : set) {
  System.out.println("Key :"+me.getKey() +" Name : "+ me.getValue().getName()+"Age :"+me.getValue().getAge());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- [Map.entrySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) (as mentioned by org.life.java) or,
- [Map.keySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) as in this example (based on your sampled code)

Example:

```
Map<String, Person> personMap = ..... //assuming it's not null
Iterator<String> strIter = personMap.keySet().iterator();
synchronized (strIter) {
    while (strIter.hasNext()) {
        String key = strIter.next();
        Person person = personMap.get(key);

        String a = key;
        String b = person.getName();
        String c = person.getAge().toString();
        System.out.println(String.format("Key : %s Name : %s Age : %s", a, b, c));

    }
}
```