# How to return a value from a Map with a method?

Tags: java, dictionary

How does one return the int values in a situation like this?

```
import java.util.*;

    public class ShoppingCart {

    private Map<String, Purchase> shoppingCart = new HashMap<String, Purchase>();

    public void add (String product, int price) {
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase(product, 1, price);
        shoppingCart.put(product, purchase);
    }

    public int totalPrice() {
        //How do I accomplish this? I want to return all the prices summed together

        }
    }  
}
```

The constructor for the purchase method is:

```
 public Purchase(String product, int amount, int price) {
```

Comment: Not quite getting the question. Do you need the methods to be used or the algorithm for the same?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, please tag it as such - otherwise people might do all the work for you. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, got it now. I tried something similar before and understood the principle, but couldn't quite get it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over map values sum the total price

This code for instance will work.

```
 public int totalPrice() {
      int sum = 0;
       for(Purchase p:shoppingCart.values()){
            sum+=p.getPrice();
       }
       return sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop through the values in the Map ([Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29)). As this is most likely homework, I'll let you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

[Iterate through map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995463/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-map-of-string-pojo) and sum the price of each purchase

Answer (score 0):

```
public int totalPrice() {
    int i = 0;
    for(Purchase purchase : shoppingCart.values()) {
      i += purchase.getPrice();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Map<String, Purchase>  map = new HashMap<String, Purchase> ();

    for(String value : map.values()) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In below code, you do not need to run for loop again...
 import java.util.*;

```
    public class ShoppingCart {

    private int sum = 0;    

    private Map<String, Purchase> shoppingCart = new HashMap<String, Purchase>();

    public void add (String product, int price) {
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase(product, 1, price);
        if(!shoppingCart.contains(product)){
             shoppingCart.put(product, purchase);
             sum += price;
        }
    }

    public int totalPrice() {
        return price;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: in map, key must be unique. And if you add product second time in the hashmap, it will overwrite existing value with new value.. And I have updated the code, if any product already added in the hashmap, it will not be added second time

Comment: Indeed, you will override the amount of the price and add the new price to the sum, but you won't remove the old one. EDIT: I don't think that's a good design either. If the caller is not allowed to add the same product twice, I'd throw an exception. The way it is now, the code pretends that an add-call was successful when nothing actually happened.

Comment: if any product is already added in the hashmap, it will not be added in the hashmap again as well as price will also not added in the total sum. I have put ! in if condition..