# Sorting an hashmap with Integer as Key and ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have situation where there is a HashMap as

`Map<Integer,ArrayList> key = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList>()`;

The array list has [rankOfCard,suitOfCard]

I want to sort this Map in such a way that If the value is

```
(1,[3,1])
(2,[2,4])
(3,[1,3])
(4,[1,2])
(5,[2,3])
```

Output should be :

```
(4,[1,2])
(3,[1,3])
(5,[2,3])
(2,[2,4])
(1,[3,1])
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It appears you are using an ArrayList when a class like `Card` would be better.  HashMap is an unsorted map, I suspect you don't need to sort it, instead you want to *display* them in a particular order.

Comment: Just what I was writing :) In Java you don't model a tuple with a `List`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I understand that you are asking me to use a class Card containing Rank and suit attribute . am I right ?

Comment: @Meenakshi If that is what the data means, yes.  This will make sorting the values more logical as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Iterate through entry set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995463/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-map-of-string-pojo) and `Collection.sort(entry.value())`

Answer (score 0):

A `Map` is not sorted, so it's not the right data structure for your task.
A `SortedMap` sorts on *keys*, so it's no good as well, since you want your map sorted by *value*.

Your question does not clarify what the key of the `Map` is, but maybe you could use a custom class in a regular `List`, and have the class implement the `Comparable` interface, or implement an external `Comparator`, to sort the `List`.