# Iterating over hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)
>   [How can I iterate over a map of <String, POJO>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995463/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-map-of-string-pojo)

I've written the following piece of code and am stuck on iterating over the hashmap.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class demo
{
    public static void main(String v[]) {
        ArrayList<String> contactIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        contactIds.add("2");
        contactIds.add("3");

        HashMap names = new HashMap();
        names =  getNames(contactIds);

        // I want to get the total size of the hashmap  - names
        // for ex now there are 6 elements inside hashmap.
        // How can I get that count?

    }


    private static HashMap getNames(ArrayList contactIds) {
        HashMap names = new HashMap();
        String params = null;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<contactIds.size();i++) {
            params = contactIds.get(i).toString();

            list.add(0,"aer-1");
            list.add(1,"aer-2");
            list.add(2,"aer-3");

            names.put(params,list) ;
         }

        return names;
    }
}
```

In this code, there are six elments inside the map, now in the main method how can I iterate over the map and get the total count?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is asked - and answered - here:

[How to efficiently iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: but how can i get the total count of elements inside hashmap.
for instance there are 3 elements added for key 1 and key 2.
now i wanted the total size i.e. 6 . is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).  You're looking for `HashMap.size()` for the total count and `HashMap.values()` for all of the values in the map, or `HashMap.entries()` for each pair of key and value.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Map' data structure isn't a Collection object but Sets are.

The most common method to iterate over a Map is using the underlying .entrySet method.

```
// For each loop
for ( Entry<String, String> entry : names ) {
    System.out.println( String.format( "(%s, %s)", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() ) );
}

// Iterator
Iterator iterator = names.entrySet().iterator
while( iterator.hasNext() ){
     Entry entry = iterator.next()
     System.out.println( String.format( "(%s, %s)", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() ) );
}
```

If are interested in finding the total number of Map nodes, use the .size() method.

EDIT:

Since you want the total size of each list stored within the map, you could do something like this.

```
Iterator iterator = names.entrySet().iterator
int count = 0;

while( iterator.hasNext() ){
     Entry entry = iterator.next()
     count += entry.getValue().size()
}
```

Comment: but how can i get the total count of elements inside hashmap. for instance there are 3 elements added for key 1 and key 2. now i wanted the total size i.e. 6 . is it possible ?

Comment: there is no method named size ()

Comment: What data structure are you using for values in the map? In your code it looks like an ArrayList which is a collection data structure so it should have a .size() method.