# How merge list when combine two hashMap objects in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two `HashMap`s defined like so:

```
HashMap<String, List<Incident>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<Incident>>();
HashMap<String, List<Incident>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<Incident>>();
```

Also, I have a 3rd `HashMap` Object:

```
HashMap<String, List<Incident>> map3;
```

and the merge list when combine both.

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-of-same-type-in-java

Comment: This is quite a different question than the "How can I combine two HashMap objects containing the same types?" This question is about combining **Multi-value** maps. The problem is that a solution for combining the values in the `List<Incident>` is needed. map.putAll() will replace the list, not combine the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you can't. map3 doesn't have the correct types to merge map1 and map2 into it.

However if it was also a `HashMap<String, List<Incident>>`. You could use the [putAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method.

```
map3 = new HashMap<String, List<Incident>>();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

If you wanted to merge the lists inside the HashMap. You could instead do this.

```
map3 = new HashMap<String, List<Incident>>();
map3.putAll(map1);
for(String key : map2.keySet()) {
    List<Incident> list2 = map2.get(key);
    List<Incident> list3 = map3.get(key);
    if(list3 != null) {
        list3.addAll(list2);
    } else {
        map3.put(key,list2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe OP want to merge `"a"->[1,2]` and `"a"->[3,4]` into `"a"->[1,2,3,4]`, since the value of the map is a `List`.

Comment: Good, point, i'll add something on that.

Comment: yes, i want to merge list

Answer (score 4):

create third map and use `putAll()` method to add data from ma

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

HashMap<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

You have ***different*** type in question for `map3` if that is not by mistake [then you need to iterate through both map using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995463/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-map-of-string-pojo) `EntrySet`

Answer (score 0):

Use [commons collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#union-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
Map<String, List<Incident>> combined = CollectionUtils.union(map1, map2);
```

If you want an Integer map, I suppose you could apply the .hashCode method to all values in your Map.

Comment: `CollectionUtils.union` doesn't work with maps, only collections.

Answer (score -1):

HashMap has a `putAll` method.

Refer this :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html