# How to join or merge List of HashMap in java 8

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, java-8, hashmap

I have list of hashmap and I want to join value if key is same below I have mentioned input and expected output .I have gone through many question answer related to this problem still couldn't found solution.

**INPUT :**

```
[
  {
    "id": "316",
    "text1": true
  },
  {
    "id": "316",
    "text2": true
  },
  {
    "id": "315",
    "text1": true
  },
  {
    "id": "315",
    "text2": true
  }
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
  {
    "id": "316",
    "text1": true,
    "text2": true
  },
  {
    "id": "315",
    "text1": true,
    "text2": true
  }
]
```

Code Snippet :

```
                    List list1= new ArrayList();
                    HashMap details= new HashMap();        
                    details.put("id", "305");
                    details.put("text1",true);    
                    list1.add(details); 
                    HashMap details2= new HashMap();
                    details2.put("id", "305");
                    details2.put("text2",true);              
        
                    list1.add(details2);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at `LinkedHashMap` is you need to keep the order, otherwise use a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`, iterate over the list, put maps into the outer map by id and use `Map` methods like `merge()`.

Comment: I tried few solution from stackoverflow  

.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types/4299742
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607850/how-merge-list-when-combine-two-hashmap-objects-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: HashSet keys=new HashSet();
        keys.add("316");
        keys.add("315");

        keys.forEach(id-> {
            list1.forEach(val -> {

                if (((LinkedHashMap) (val)).get("id").equals((String.valueOf(id)))) {

                    programList.add(val);
                }

            });

        });
this is  sample code snippet which i tried

Comment: Please reread my first comment: don't try to _cast_ the maps to `LinkedHashMap` but use it to store the merged maps.

Comment: Stop using raw types. Include the necessary declarations, e.g. of `list1` and `list2`, in the question. JSON-dumps are not helpful for Java question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Thomas comment you can do like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> mapMap = new HashMap<>();
    list.forEach(map -> map.entrySet().forEach(entry ->
            mapMap.merge((String) map.get("id"), map, (map1, map2) -> {
                map1.putAll(map2);
                return map1;
            }))
    );

System.out.println(mapMap.values());
```

Comment: it worked . instead of merging into new map I was trying to merge into existing one only . any ways thanks for your great help .